# How do I convert a multidimensional array to a json object (node js)

Tags: arrays, json, node.js

I'm fetching a couple of values from an API, and I'm storing them as an array. I'm trying to convert this array into JSON objects. This is the output I'm currently getting:

```
[ { Service: '1e',
    Maintainability: 'A',
    Issues: 2,
    Coverage: 1.2 } ]  
[ { Service: '2',
    Maintainability: 'B',
    Issues: 2,
    Coverage: 0.6 } ] 
[ { Service: '3',
    Maintainability: 'C',
    Issues: 5,
    Coverage: 0.2 } ] 
[ { Service: '4',
    Maintainability: 'A',
    Issues: 1,
    Coverage: 1 } ]
```

I need the output to look like this:

```
[ { Service: '1e',
    Maintainability: 'A',
    Issues: 2,
    Coverage: 1.2 },  
  { Service: '2',
    Maintainability: 'B',
    Issues: 2,
    Coverage: 0.6 }, 
  { Service: '3',
    Maintainability: 'C',
    Issues: 5,
    Coverage: 0.2 }, 
  { Service: '4',
    Maintainability: 'A',
    Issues: 1,
    Coverage: 1 } ]
```

Any help please?

Comment: what have you done so far?

Comment: have you tried concatenating the separate arrays into on using Array.concat?
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat

Sample: [ { 'hello': 'world' } ] .concat([{'convert': 'to'}], [{'json': 'please'}])

Comment: I don't see any "multidimensional arrays"… Those are just arrays with 1 object in each of them.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example:

```
let arr1=[{a:1}];
let arr2=[{b:2}];
let arr3=[{c:3}];
let Result = arr1.concat(arr2,arr3); // Result = [{a:1},{b:2},{c:3}]

let arr4=[
    [{a:1}],
    [{b:2}],
    [{c:3}],
];
let Result2 = [].concat(...arr4); //Result2 = [{a:1},{b:2},{c:3}]
```

As the same,Map is also a good idea

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting this:

```
arr = [ [ { Service: '1e',
    Maintainability: 'A',
    Issues: 2,
    Coverage: 1.2 } ]  ,
  [ { Service: '2',
    Maintainability: 'B',
    Issues: 2,
    Coverage: 0.6 } ],
  [ { Service: '3',
    Maintainability: 'C',
    Issues: 5,
    Coverage: 0.2 } ],
  [ { Service: '4',
    Maintainability: 'A',
    Issues: 1,
    Coverage: 1 } ] ]
```

The desired array is:

```
desiredArr = arr.map(x => x[0]);
```

or you can do this:

```
desiredArr = arr.reduce((a, b) => a.concat(b), []);
```